# Plot along different dimensions

Tags: julia

I have the following basic code. The first line sums p along dimension 1 to create a 1 x column array. The next line plot A. Unfortunately, it seems that Julia assumes it must plot many lines (in this case just points) along dimension 2.

```
A = sum(p,dims = 1)
plot(A)
```

So, my question is, how can I plot a simple line when the data is in a 1 x column array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you use `Plots.jl`. The following is from `Plots.jl`'s documentation.

> If the argument [to `plot`] is a "matrix-type", then *each column will map to a series*, cycling through columns if there are fewer columns than series. In this sense, a vector is treated just like an "nx1 matrix".

The number of series `plot(a)` tries to plot is the number of columns in `a`.

To get a single series, you can do one of the followings

```
plot(vec(a)) # `vec` will give you a vector view of `a` without an allocation

plot(a') # or `plot(transpose(a))`. `transpose` does not allocate a new array

plot(a[:]) # this allocates a new array so you should probably avoid it
```

Comment: plot(a') works in my situation. This too is much like (or exactly like) MATLAB, except MATLAB doesn't seem to require the transposition for plotting. In MATLAB I learned it was usually bad practice to get into a situation where transposing is necessary. Is that true in Julia as well? What are the costs here?

Comment: In Julia, `b = a'` does not really take a transpose. It is a lazy operation, that does *not* allocate a new array and copy values into it. See the doc for [`transpose`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/LinearAlgebra/index.html#Base.transpose). There is not really a penalty even if your array is extremely big.

Comment: The behavior of `Plots.plot` for this matter is the same as MATLAB's `plot` except that the case for `1xn` matrix (e.g. a row vector in MATLAB) is a special case for MATLAB's `plot`. Note that this is not about Julia but rather about the implementation `Plots.jl` package you choose to use. If you directly use `GR.jl`, for example, you could plot a `1xn` matrix without a need for transpose.