# The legends is going outside of the plot. How to avoid it

Tags: julia, plots.jl

Drawing using code below

```
p = scatter(; title = "a", titlefont=font(12), 
            xlabel = "message size",
xscale = :log10, xlims, xticks, ylabel = "time [sec]",
ylims, yscale = :log10, legend=:outertopright, 
    left_margin=15Plots.mm, bottom_margin=15Plots.mm,
guidefont=font(8), xtickfont=font(5), 
   width=2000,height=2000, legend_margin=5, 
   legendfont=font(5))

scatter!( p, data1[:, 1],  data2[:, 5], 
       color=colors[index], ma=0.9   )
```

[image: plot by code above]

The legends is going outside of the plot. How to avoid it or increase the size of whole graph.

```
data1 = [0,4,8,16, ,32 ,64 ,128 ,256 ,512 ,1024 ,2048 ,4096 ,8192 ,16384 ,32768 ,65536 ,131072 ,262144 ,524288 ,1048576 ,2097152 ,4194304]

data2=[3.08E-06 ,6.20E-06 ,6.26E-06 ,3.75E-05 ,4.36E-05 ,4.37E-05 ,4.52E-05 ,4.70E-05 ,5.58E-05 ,5.83E-05 ,6.67E-05 ,8.77E-05 ,0.000134397 ,0.000229329 ,0.000424682 ,0.000868432 ,0.00035778 ,0.000452593 ,0.000561347 ,0.000750234 ,0.001281027 ,0.002102504]
```

Comment: How is it possible to put 114 legends on a figure that size?

Comment: @AboAmmar I also tried to increase the length and width (width=3000,height=3000) but its not working.

Comment: from a presentation angle, I don't think it's a good idea to make a plot like this to begin with, even if you can make the bottom white space go larger

Comment: Why list the Y values as a legend on the plot? Make a table for that, and plot some kind of summary or histogram instead.

Comment: it looks like you only have 5(?) distinct colors, so at most you should only have 5 distinct legend entries. If you need help with doing that let me know and I'm happy to show you an example of how you could do that with your `index` variable (which looks to me to be assigning the colors and thus should also assign the labels).

Comment: This is an easy trap to fall into. `plots` arguments are sensitive to the shape of the input (e.g. vector vs. row matrix). And I suspect the OP is trying to address what he saw as "every point that should be in the same series is a different color" just by specifying the colors.

So Khalid, what are the elements of `data1` and `data2`?

Comment: @NickBauer I have updated the data set in the question.

Comment: @KhalidBinHuda - With that data you posted, I'm not getting what you see. What does reproduce it is, for instance, `scatter(data1', data2', xscale = :log10, yscale = :log10, color = [:blue :red])`. It's best to run all the code you posted fresh to make sure the example is working.

Comment: Good point Nick. That answer is also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56017562/plot-along-different-dimensions